# How to execute an import exe/dll from memory

Tags: unpacking, patch-reversing

i dumped a exe/dll file from the memory with OllyDumpEx, now i understand i need to fix the address or something like this to use the dll or to run the exe, so how  can i do that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. This could be rather hard. The executable images contain relocation information which gets resolved by the loader before runtime. You seem to want to restore relocation information based on an image taken from memory, though. Additionally since there are other rules for a mapped image file and an image file on disk, relocations aren't the only change that's taking place.

Comment: can you explain me the process of it? or send me a guide?